# simplest way of recording 8 bit signed mono 16khz sound with alsa (in a way it's compatible with pulse)?

Tags: c++, linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm totally lost, does anyone have a very simple example of how to record a sound using ALSA with c++? the only thing i need is the raw samples as signed bytes for feeding them to another part of my program. All the examples i found googling seem to have issues with PulseAudio or don't cover what i need.